# display pdf file and disable the right click option. what are way to implement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I tried with embed, iframe, and object and was unable to provide the option to disable the right-click functionality. I am checking here what are alternative ways to display pdf and disable the right click.

Answer (score 1):

PDF controls display on the browser by default and you don´t have control of that.

One workaround is to create a custom pdf preview in js+blazor = https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2021/how-to-build-a-blazor-pdf-viewer-with-pspdfkit/

The second workaround is to convert pdf into jpg for example (if is just a document preview, jpg is a good option)